# Does the mirror modifier have to be applied in order to a complete a UV map of the model?

Tags: uv, mirror

I want to know if it's possible to have the complete UV map of an object while still retaining its mirror modifier. I have unwrapped the model, but it can only do so for the edited side.

I'm using Blender 2.75.

Comment: I think you can only export the 'real' non modifier-generated side, but since it is mirrored after export all you have to do is either mirror or extend it in your image editing software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  The Mirror modifier extends UV's as well.  So if you have textures mapped to your model, it will map to both sides identically.  If you are fine with that, then no.

If you need to edit both sides independently, you will need to apply the modifier and further unwrap your model.

Comment: Does the second option also includes the export of the UV layouts as well?

Comment: What sort of export are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

In the **Mirror** modifier panel, you can check **Mirror U** (or V) to mirror the UV horizontally (and/or vertically).

Then you can texture both sides of your model separately.

[image: Modifier > Mirror U (or V)]